# Как задать размеры элементов Activity (и самой Activity) в Java-классе?

Tags: android, activity

Мне нужно задать размеры `Activity` и всех её элементов через соответствующий `Java`-класс (через разметку не подойдёт). Если сбросите пример кода, буду благодарен.

Comment: Не совсем корректный вопрос как мне кажется. Если Вас интересуют элементы активити то разметка так раз самое то, ну то есть в xml всё менять. Если вы хотите задать параметры через класс, ну тут такое, всё равно без xml Вам не обойтись.

Comment: Я хочу задать параметры через класс. Как мне не обойтись без xml?

Comment: Я не пойму в чём проблема перейти сделать всё в разметке? в самом классе вы по сути только обращаетесь к тем или иным элементам + иногда сэтите какие то параметры. Возможно стоит переформулировать вопрос, для того чтобы лучше понять вашу задачу?

Comment: Вы знаете ответ на тот вопрос, который я задал? Если Вы хотите помочь, а не развести тут дискуссию, но знаете ответ только как задать при помощи xml, хорошо, давайте через xml. Мне необходимо задать высоту экрана размером 100% от текущего экрана + 100dp. Элементы экрана (их три) должны иметь следующие размеры по Y: 100dp, 60% от размера экрана, 40% от размера экрана. Поможете?

Comment: Что значит "задать высоту экрана размером 100% от текущего экрана + 100dp",  чтобы можно было скролить вниз получается? Или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Да, чтобы скролить вниз, получается.

Comment: какие три элемента должны быть расположены? + они должны занимать всю ширину?

Comment: Три LinearLayout. Да, всю.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально Вам нужно создать xml файл, после чего в самом классе сделать inflate данной xml(по названию уже которому вы зададите).

Выглядеть это будет приимерно следующим образом(в качестве примера ввёл туда по EditText'у для того чтобы видеть как оно выглядит вообще), для того чтобы изменить параметры которые вам нужно подогнать, меняйте просто значения в `android:layout_height`на то сколько вам нужно(видимость можете увидеть при нажатии на Design в поле разметки), если же вы хотите растянуть на весь экран, то используйте match_parent.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/second"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Это не является решением проблемы. Вы описали нанесение стандартной разметки в xml, с которой знаком любой начинающий android-разработчик, а решение моего вопроса требует более глубокого знания Android. Извините, но Вы не смогли мне помочь. Рекомендую Вам изучить вопрос и попытаться ответить на него ещё раз.